# Не отображается баннер с рекламой. ADBannerView: Unhandled error

Tags: swift, in-app-purchases

Здравствуйте, коллеги.

Добавил в своё приложение отображение рекламных баннеров. При запуске в симуляторе на консоль выходят сообщения об ошибках следующего содержания:

> ADBannerView: Unhandled error (no delegate or delegate does not
> implement didFailToReceiveAdWithError:)... Code=4 "Application has iAd
> Network configuration error" Code=5 "Banner view is visible but does
> not have content"

Те же самые ошибки но в российской локализации выглядят так:

> Code=4 "В программе имеется ошибка конфигурации сети iAd"
>
> Code=5 "Режим отображения баннеров включен, но баннер пуст"

Проблема сводится к тому, что баннер не отображается

Проштудировал интернет на эту тему, в основном все ответы сводятся к тому, что надо указать делегата, либо имплементировать метод didFailToReceiveAdWithError. Делегата я назначил. Если имплементировать метод обработки ошибок, то ошибка на консоль не выводится, но проблемы это не решает.

```
import UIKit
import iAd
import StoreKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {

@IBOutlet weak var restorePurchases: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var removeAdButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var adBanner: ADBannerView!

var productToPurchase = SKProduct()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

adBanner.hidden = false
adBanner.delegate = self
removeAdButton.hidden = false

let userDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let paymentQueue = SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue()

if userDefault.objectForKey("Advert") == nil {
    paymentQueue.addTransactionObserver(self)
    getProductInformation()
}

if let transactionState = userDefault.objectForKey("Advert") {
    if transactionState as! String == "Purchased" {
        adBanner.removeFromSuperview()
        removeAdButton.hidden = true
        removeAdButton.enabled = false
    } else {
        paymentQueue.addTransactionObserver(self)
        getProductInformation()
    }
}
```

}`

Привожу часть кода, для того, что бы показать, что делегата я назначил. При необходимости могу выложить остальную часть кода.

Кроме того не работает кнопка отключения рекламы. При нажатии на нее выходит сообщение на консоль: Ошибка: nil, а затем алёрт контроллер "Sign In". Нажимаю на Use Existing Apple ID и получаю в ответ ошибку:

> Can not connect to iTunes Store. В консоли получаю следующее: "Ошибка:
> Optional(Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes
> Store" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes
> Store})"

Я так понимаю, что эти вещи взаимосвязанны и если решить одну проблему, то решится и вторая. Хотя могу ошибаться.

Все это я тестирую в симуляторе. Может быть из за этого вся проблема? Со своей учетной записи из айтюнса и в аппстора я вышел.

---

Подключил реальное устройство, теперь удалось сделать встроенную покупку. Ошибок на консоль ни каких не выходит, но баннер по прежнему пустой. Это так и должно быть?

Answer (score 2):

с 01 июля 2016г сеть iAD больше не работает, Apple её больше не использует
[ссылка](https://developer.apple.com/iad/)
Используйте другие способы монетизации (Admob, Appodeal и прочие)

Comment: Спасибо за информацию